# UIWebView ignores inline anchor/link

Tags: html, swift, uiwebview, anchor, inline

I'm using a `UIWebView`that loads HTML from a database string using `webView.loadHTMLString(self.htmlContent, baseURL: nil)`

The `htmlContent` contains the following:

```
<ul class="anchorNavigation">
  <li>
    <a href="#parsys_47728" class="">1. Inline Test Link</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#parsys_00061" class="">2. Inline Test Link</a>
  </li>
  ...
</ul>
```

... and later in the HTML:

```
...
<a href="#" name="parsys_00061"></a>
...
```

However, whenever I click the inline link in the `webView` nothing happens.

### What I've tried so far:

- Changing the anchor tag to 'real' valid W3C HTML. E.g. `<a id='parsys_47728'>Test</a>`
- Saving the HTML to a file in the temp directory and loading it using `loadRequest()`. E.g. `let path = tempDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("content.html")` and `webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: path))`
- Intercepting the `loadRequest` method by implementing the `func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool` delegate. The `request.URL` says something strange like: *"applewebdata://1D9D74C2-BBB4-422F-97A7-554BCCD0055A#parsys_47728"*

I don't have any idea anymore how to achieve this. I know from previous projects that local HTML files in the bundle work with inline links. I just cannot figure out why this doesn't work.

Help much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Could you recheck that `webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool` returns `true` for your request? If yes you could change URL scheme from `applewebdata` to `file` just for debugging and test it.

Answer (score 1):

If there's a fragment (e.g., #anchorName), then use JavaScript to scroll.  Otherwise, assume it's a link without a fragment and use openURL.

```
// UIWebViewDelegate
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked ) {
        // NSLog(@"request.URL  %@",request.URL); // e.g., file:///.../myApp.app/#anchorName
        NSString *anchorName = request.URL.fragment; // e,g, "anchorName"    
        if ( anchorName ) {
            [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString swf:@"window.location.hash='%@';",anchorName]];
            return NO;

        } else { // assume http://
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[request URL]];
            return NO;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

I'm still looking for a way to have the scroll position change smoothly (animated) rather than jumping.

Comment: fragments can exist on internal or external links. If it is external you probably want to attempt to follow the link instead of using javascript to find the corresponding anchor tag. How do you tell if the link is external if the baseURL basically doesn't exist because the scheme is "applewebdata://" followed by a guid referencing a local file?